# Spring cloud gateway proxyexchange does not handle response in case of Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm writing a simple code, which acts as gateway for another micro-service (call it MSB). the request from client is being passed from the gateway to the MSB API successfully.

The response is returned back from MSB to the gateway successfully in case the request passes ( i.e. replied with 200  with no logical / business exception )

In case of error from MSB, the response is not being parsed and the gateway receives 500

Gateway code

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createReward(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return proxy
                .uri(rewardsUrl)
                .post();
    }
```

This is the response received at the gateway,

```
<400 Bad Request,[B@6673d42c,{Content-Type=[application/json], 
Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], 
Date=[Thu, 14 Jan 2021 14:48:25 GMT], Connection=[close]}>
```

This is the response / exception thrown by MSB

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-14T14:38:17.190+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/capiter/api/v1/rewards"
}
```

Comment: I'm using postman as trial, and this is postman's response:
Error: Parse Error: Invalid character in chunk size, i thought this might help.

Answer (score 0):

since proxy passes request body, it may be the issue with the consuming the response from the gateway? Maybe omitting the `byte[]` would help? And examine the gateway endpoint you are sending the exception too.